# excel-vba contraseña para todas las celdas de una columna

Tags: excel, vba

¿cómo puedo hacer por código para que al pulsar cualquier celda de la columna A me me pida una contraseña?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que jugar con el evento [Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then 'si la celda seleccionada está en la columna 1
    'resto de tu código
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: gracias @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes